# Question feedback

Tags: discussion, specific-question

### The situation

Earlier today, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216096/change-home-of-wsl-to-mnt-c-users-yourwindowsuser/51217412) which was initially downvoted without feedback and then back up.

Later somebody disagreed and voted it back up, averaging it out to 0 again.

### Why I ask

I asked for feedback on the downvote but did not recieve any and wondered what made my question sub-standard.

I now hope by asking here to get feedback on the quality of my question, formatting and overall hints to improve my question since I must, when in doubt, think that the first downvote was legitimate and there is indeed a problem with the quality of my question.

Comment: Just don't tag a [windows] question with [linux].  You'll inevitably encounter some users that hate their parent's operating system.

Comment: Generally people who downvote and don't leave a comment, won't leave a comment. Ask on meta is probably a better way.

Comment: @HansPassant this totally backfired. I wanted feedback to improve my question and got it. However I exposed my question so much that I lost so many upvotes that I now face a question ban. I came here for feedback. Not to have my account shredded. This is a weird situation where I want to be a good member and ask for constructive feedback and as a result get denied from asking ever again (let's face it. Ban's are very hard to lift.)

Comment: You didn't remove the tag until half an hour ago.  Gack.  Ignoring advice is your prerogative, little I can do.  There might be better places to ask WSL questions, the MSDN forums ought to be a safer.

Comment: @HansPassant The downvotes didn't change since you told me this. They went to -5 quick and stayed there. Also, yes, it's advice, however I feel like I shouldn't edit tags to save my question since it is ACTUALLY a Windows/Linux question. They make sense in this case.

Answer (score 12):

I *barely* have any idea on what you're asking about.

So, let me explain.

- You present that you're using Cygwin on Windows.
- You present that you want to move *away* from that.
- You present that you're trying to modify the passwd file but it's failing.

At *no* point do you stop to explain what it is you're doing or what your goal is at all.

If you want us to help you out then you would be best served on explaining what your ultimate motive is.  It is easily the case that this question may live better on Super User, but before you repost it *there*, it should be clear what it is you're attempting to accomplish and how you're attempting to accomplish it.

Comment: > I want to **replace** Cygwin or at least check if it's viable to **replace** Cygwin

,is not viable as a reason?

Comment: Okay.  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You knew these questions would come - you even put it in your question "_Please let's focus on the how, not why_"

Comment: Cygwin is huge and WSL isn't. It also doubles as a replacement for a dual boot system. I like the flexibility, but those reasons feel too obvious since the question was about the problem, not the reason.

Comment: csmckelvey people seem obsessed with the why, rather then the how. I don't want to discuss flavours, but get a solution. I think this is what SO is about. Opinion based questions are discouraged for a reason.

Comment: What you illustrated there was a motivation @BlkPengu, not necessarily a *reason*.   It's unclear to me what a move would do for you unless you were specifically trying to solve something.  Note that this reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248); you're facing *some* kind of pain with Cygwin and you want to work around it, but instead of talking about the pain you want to talk about the workaround which makes less than intuitive sense.

Comment: There are other *nix shells available for Windows nowadays (I wouldn't really know off the top of my head, I just use Linux straight), and I've seen the need for installing/using Cygwin fall to the wayside anyway.  So I suppose what you're asking is begging a few more questions yet.

Comment: @Makoto: Does it really matter why he's doing it? I mean, every time someone posts a question about drawing cubes in OpenGL, I could ask why they want to do that. But that's not going to resolve their problem. I understand the XY problem, but that only matters when X is a fundamentally bad/impossible idea. Now, I don't know enough about Cygwin to know whether that is the case here, so maybe that's the case. But if it is, then that probably is what needs to be said.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  It motivates solutions.  Cygwin is intentionally installed as a *nix compatibility layer shell, and removing it and replacing it with something else implies that they want to do more.  Now this is possible, but it really does depend on what it is they want to do that Cygwin can't (and in fairness, Cygwin really can't do a whole lot).  It's not good enough on its own for a full *nix shell.  At this point it's kinda critical that the OP clarify their goals so that we can actually see what the real problem is.

Comment: @NicolBolas / Makoto this whole thing blew up in my face. I asked for constructive feedback and got it. In the future there is one more rule I now know so I don't ask the wrong kind of questions. 
I really want to be a good member. However in the process i exposed my question to so many people that i now face a question ban.